# Which signal should i be using?

Tags: openttd

I have got a small railway line that transports oil from oil pumps to a refinery. I want to add another train and so have made a siding so that they may pass unharmed (would be bad if they crashed) but I don't know which signals I should be using and where to put them. Also, where should I put the signals for the engine shed(yellow) Here is a picture.
[image: Train one(blue) waits for train 1(red) to finish loading and pass. Then train 2 moves on and loads while train 1 waits.]

If there is a better way to do this please tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, if you can *possibly* afford it, raise that one segment of land. It'll drastically reduce the slowdown.

Two, what you want are one-way-path signals just after the split, pointing in the direction you want each branch to go. Refer to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124936/can-someone-explain-me-openttds-train-signals-quick-and-easy?rq=1) for more details on signals.

Comment: Never mind. I have found a better way of doing this with block signals and exit signals and then found it wasn't very efficient.